# Seg Fault while OR operation

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I have following piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#define PORT_TYPE 0x01000000
main(){
    uint32_t port_id = 0x00123456;
    uint32_t *iptr = NULL;
    iptr = (uint32_t *) (sizeof(uint32_t));
    *iptr = (PORT_TYPE | port_id);
}
```

It is throwing me seg fault. My intention to OR both variable it to get a 32-bit value (0x01123456)

Comment: Why is dereferencing null pointer giving you segmentation fault, hmmm....

Comment: @zubergu - sorry, question was edited before I saw it.

Comment: @MartinJames yet the problem is almost the same, except that now you're not dereferencing NULL, you're dereferencing addres 4, which is still a veeery bad idea. Consider sharing with us, what you want to achieve, this way we're not getting anywhere near helping you.

Answer (score 4):

You are dereferencing the pointer `iptr`, whose value is not a valid, writable memory location. That triggers undefined behavior, in your case a segmentation fault.

To just compute the value, you could do e.g.

```
printf("0x%08x\n", PORT_TYPE | port_id);
```

To compute the pointer that is the bitwise-OR of `PORT_TYPE` and `port_id`,  you can do:

```
uint32_t *iptr = (uint32_t *) (PORT_TYPE | port_id);
```

The cast is necessary since the values being bitwise-OR:ed are not pointers (you can't bitwise-OR pointers).

Note that the above *does not* ever dereference the resulting pointer, since there's no guarantee (and it is, in general, *very unlikely*) that doing so would be valid.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The question was edited. Now it's even stranger. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has *little* to do with OR operation.

Problem here is , you're trying to dereference `NULL` memory, which leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) showing a side-effect as segmentation fault.

In your code, you've `iptr` set to `NULL`. You are not supposed to access `NULL` memory. You've to allocate memory to `iptr` before you actually *use* it.

Try this

```
uint32_t *iptr = NULL;
iptr = malloc (sizeof (uint32_t *));   // allocate memory dynamically.

if (iptr)                             //check for success of malloc
    *iptr = (PORT_TYPE | port_id);
else
    // don't use iptr, do something else, or return.
```

and once you're done, don't forget to `free()` the memory.

Note: Also, it is a good practice to use `int main()` and a `return` statement.

---

EDIT:

as per your latest edit,

```
 iptr = (uint32_t *) (sizeof(uint32_t));
```

***does not*** allocate memeory.

Comment: After allocation memory with following statement before assigning value to it, compiler still throws seg fault.
iptr = (uint32_t *) (sizeof(uint32_t));

Comment: @RajS `(uint32_t *) (sizeof(uint32_t))` does not allocate memory.

Comment: @RajS did you try my approach to allocate memory?

Comment: Won't `iptr = (uint32_t *) (sizeof(uint32_t));` make iptr point to a 32-bit block of memory address ?

Comment: @RajS No, absolutely not. `sizeof` __operator__ (yes, not function) returns the size as `size_t`, not an address. Casting that to `(uint32_t *)` and expecting it will be a valid address, both are wrong.

Comment: @RajS No. It will assign `(uint32_t *) (sizeof(uint32_t))` to `iptr`. Which is equal to `(uint32_t *) 4`, which is equal to `4`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write through a NULL pointer:

```
*iptr = <anything>
```

would cause a segmentation fault, because iptr points to NULL. You can't write on NULL.

Comment: After allocation memory with following statement before assigning value to it, compiler still throws seg fault. `iptr = (uint32_t *) (sizeof(uint32_t));`

Answer (score 1):

Replace `*iptr` with `iptr` to assign to `iptr`:

```
iptr = (PORT_TYPE | port_id);
```

This will assign the result of `(PORT_TYPE | port_id)` to `iptr`.

---

Using `*iptr` would have assigned to the memory at address `(uint32_t *) (sizeof(uint32_t))` (which is equal to `4`, a nonsensical memory address for a variable, on most systems anyway), which is why the seg fault happened.

---

To dynamically allocate memory to `iptr`:

```
iptr = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t));
```

This will allocate `sizeof(uint32_t)` bytes of memory and assign the address of that memory to `iptr`.

Comment: Why do all those other replies miss that iptr was assigned something, (equally useless on most systems), after the NULL?

Comment: @MartinJames The OP modified the code afterwards. It was `NULL` at first.

Comment: Ah... oh... I downvoted the other answers:(  Now I have to reverse it:)